# iOS Custom Back Button without calling method in every View Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, back-button, objective-c-category

I would like a more elegant solution to changing the back button for an Application's Navigation Bar. All the answers I've seen only talk about customizing a button and then adding at least one line of code to each View Controller for the new button to display.

I have a category where I modify the Navigation Bar's background and Title. It's a category of `UINavigationBar`. The category calls `willMoveToWindow:` to call methods each time a new view is pushed on the Navigation Controller.

So here's how the code to create a new button would look:

```
- (void)applyCustomButton{
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];    
}
```

The problem here is that `self.navigationItem` won't work here. I don't want to bore you with all the things I tried categorizing, but that property only works on View Controllers (I think)?

You don't have to give me a solution for the code above, maybe you have a better way of customizing the Back Button on the Navigation Bar without having to write code on every View Controller Class I have. I just hate repetition because maintaining code like that sucks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subclass UIViewController, add your code, and then inherit from your subclass for all of your viewcontrollers...

Comment: I tried making a cat. of UIViewController, the problem is how do you call the method to style the button. ViewDidLoad, or ViewWillAppear cannot be used because they're methods being implemented by the ViewController itself.

Comment: **Subclass** UIViewcontroller, add your code...